# An active verb "to find peace in" something

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary, active-voice

I'm looking for an active verb which means something along the lines of "to take or find peace in" something.  Something like *soothe* is the opposite of what I want, in the sense that the something is the thing doing the soothing. e.g.,

> The river soothed him.

But I would want "him" to be the subject.  This would result in...

> He was soothed by the river.

...but this is passive rather than active.  Is there such an active verb?  A single word that means something like "find peace in" in the following?

> I find peace in the trickling of the river.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that there isn't a non-reflective verb for this.  It seems like you essentially want [subject] [active-verb] [causation noun]'... by definition, the subject invokes, so it would have to be reflexive to emphasize the "order of operations", so to say.  Good question -- really made me think.  I'm curious if there is such a non-reflexive construct out there now.

Answer (score 3):

If you're committed to a single word, I would look at the reflexive verbs lull, quiet, or ease. Soothe would work.

The resulting sentence would be something like,

> "I lull myself by the river."
>
> "She quiets herself by the river."

But, if you want a single unreflexive verb, I would use **unwind** or **relax** (somewhat obvious).

> "I unwind by the river."

Comment: +1 These aren't bad.  They don't quite give the *connection* to the river, though, since the *self* becomes the direct object and the river becomes part of a prepositional phrase.  The river sort of becomes incidental.

Comment: @JeffGohlke I was worried about that, but couldn't find a better single word :/

Answer (score 2):

Consider "I **drift away** in the trickling of the river"

and "I **float away** in the trickling of the river."

Comment: I would worry that these phrases in this context could be taken to mean someone literally floating/drifting away in a river as opposed to something metaphorical unless that was made clear by context.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious one that hasn't been mentioned here is *rested*.

> He rested to the trickling of the brook.

Granted, I find the *to* to be a little bit awkward, but it helps emphasize that the rest achived was due to the trickling of the water rather than simply resting physically by or physically in the water.

A more metaphorical option would be *commune*.  Generally this means something along the lines of "intimate communication," but since *the trickling of the water* is a much more nebulous concept it invokes (at least in my mind) some concept of the subject finding peace or attaining some sort of peaceful mental state:

> He communed with the steady trickling of the water by the brook.

Hope those help, but I don't think they're any better (or worse) than what's been suggested already.

Comment: Looking at your comments above, I realize you're looking for a transitive verb where the river's the direct object.  Both of these connect with river via a prepositional phrase, so it may not be what you're looking for...

Comment: Actually, "communed" is quite nice.  I'll have to think on that one.  I think it conveys what I'm looking for fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the verb *[comfort](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/comfort)* but would need to add a reflexive, such as *himself*.

> Improve the mood of or restore a sense of well-being to:

While not a single word (and no more succinct than *find peace*), the phrase *take comfort* conveys a similar meaning.

Interestingly, the term *[self-soothe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-soothe)* is used to describe the beahvior of infants who can calm themselves without adult intervention.

SUPPLEMENT: You also might consider metaphorical terms such as *melted, flowed, merged, floated, glided, dwelt*, none of which convey his literal action, but a figurative approach to his feelings.

Answer (score 0):

"Lose" may work, as in "He lost himself in the trickling murmer of the river."

Comment: Still reflexive though eh?

Answer (score 0):

I am **tranquilized (or calmed)** by the trickling of the river.

Comment: Still passive, unfortunately. :(  `He was tranquilized/calmed by the river.`

Answer (score 0):

Lethe is defined as peace of mind

[>  ...Greek word, meaning "oblivion" or "forgetfulness." It was also the

> name of the river that flowed through Hades (the underworld of Greek 
>   mythology). Souls who drank from the river would forget all they had 
>   known in their past lives.
>
> ...When the speaker talks about "Lethean peace," he is imagining the 
>   comfort that will come with being able to forget his pain.][1](http://www.shmoop.com/ulalume/allusions.html)

&

Ataraxic [peace of mind](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/9239/ataraxia)

Answer (score 0):

Contemplate

> — vb
>
> 1. to think about intently and at length; consider calmly
> 2. ( intr ) to think intently and at length, esp for spiritual reasons; meditate
>
> see [reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contemplate). Scroll down to World English Dictionary.

This word implies calm.

Answer (score -1):

How about *Harmony*? Or something to that effect.

I and the trickling river were in harmony. Or something to that effect.

Comment: "I harmonize with the river" actually isn't half bad, though if the river is turbulent and violent, it wouldn't have a peaceful connotation.  Haha.  +1

Comment: @JeffGohlke You could harmonize with the sounds of the river. As an idea.